# Debug Feature Receiver Webapplication Scope

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-application, feature-receiver, debugging

I'm using SharePoint 2013, VS 2015, I want to Debug my Feature Activated Receiver which is WebApplication Scoped.

When I attach w3p or OWSTIMER processes the Feature doesn't show up in Central Administration. It seems like it doesn't even deploy.

When I don't attach the processes it does not stop at Breakpoints. I also tried to set Project properties

> Active Deployment Configuration = No Activation

Can anyone help me with debugging FeatureReceiver in WebApplication Scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround for your reference, insert below code to your feature receiver.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

[image]

Referenced thread:

http://www.roberthiskey.com/2012/06/debugging-farm-and-web-application.html

Comment: thanks for your Answer i knew that one. The problem with this line is that it's not consistent in finding the right VS instance. I will mark your Answer as helpful though.